# Value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}$?

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6845/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-methods-of-summing-exotic-series?noredirect=1&lq=1) old question and fascinated by the second infinite sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}.$$ This is clearly convergent (by comparison or ratio test) and, we can obtain some crude approximations of this using inequalities like $n^4\le n!\le (n!)^2,$ here the first inequality holds for all $n\ge7.$ But, I wonder if we can find the exact value of this series using (familiar) special functions/constants. How would you attack to this series?

Comment: This is [A248761](http://oeis.org/A248761) in OEIS, but no useful information is given.

Comment: The vast majority of convergent real series don't have 'nice' closed-form expressions. I've been wrong before, but this looks like it falls into that group.

Comment: Just throwing something out: denote $T(k)=\sum\limits_{n\ge1}(n!)^{-1/2k}$. Then the desired value is $T(1)$ which satisfies $$T(1)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac x{2\pi i}\mathcal M^{-1}\left(x^{-s}T(s)\sin\frac{\pi s}2\Gamma(s-1)\right)$$ where $\mathcal M^{-1}$ is the inverse Mellin transform.

Comment: Also an integral form: $$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac1{\sqrt{n!}}=\frac12\int_1^\infty\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor\psi^{(0)}(x+1)}{\sqrt{\Gamma(x+1)}}\,dx=1+\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\Gamma(x+1)}}-\frac12\int_1^\infty\frac{\{x\}\psi^{(0)}(x+1)}{\sqrt{\Gamma(x+1)}}\,dx$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the floor function, $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part and $\psi^{(0)}$ is the digamma function.