# The sum $\sum \frac{1}{(i!)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta, bessel-functions

We know the sum:

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i!)} = e.$$

This makes me wonder about the sum:

$$S = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i!)^2}.$$

It's clear that it converges and also that it's less than $e$ since all the terms are less than the first summation. But is there a closed form for it?

Numerically, it seems to be around $2.279$.

---

In general, one can define a function similar to the Riemann Zeta:

$$S(u) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i!)^u}$$

This will converge for all $u>0$. We know the closed form for $u=1$.

For large $u$, it'll just become $2$.

But I wonder if any other $u$ has a closed form. And if we wanted to extend it to the complex numbers and analytically continue it, what would we get for:

$$S(-1) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (i!)$$

Comment: You just don't. This sum most likely has no closed form. But I am positive we could find a differential equation for the function $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!^2}$

Comment: See [Bessel-Clifford function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel–Clifford_function)

Comment: $S = {}_0F_1(-; 1; 1)$.

Comment: Your first $S$ is $I_0(2)$ where $I_0$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: [$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n!}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637061/value-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1-sqrtn?noredirect=1) has no closed form yet

Answer (score 8):

Specifically for your case of $$S = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i!)^2}$$ this admits a closed form in terms of a modified bessel function of the first kind where we have
$$I_v(z) = \left(\frac z2 \right)^v \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac {z^2}4\right)^i}{(i!)\,\Gamma(v+i+1)} \iff{\color{red} {I_0(2)}} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i!)^2}$$

In general, the "closed form" of $$S(u) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i!)^u}$$ for $u\in \mathbb Z^+$ can be found by looking at the general series definition of the [hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html), and can be expressed in a sense as
$$S(u) = {}_0F_u(; \underbrace{1, 1, \dots, 1;1}_{\text{there are }u\text{ 1's}})$$

---

In regards to your limit of $$\lim_{u\to0^+}S(u)$$ I don't think your numerical evaluation was correct as Mathematica on my end claims it diverges

[image]

Comment: You're right, the limit diverges. I removed that part from the question (got too excited).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, this constant does not have a closed-form expression in terms of elementary functions. That said, we can express it in closed form in terms of the [Modified Bessel Function of the First Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1), $I_\alpha(x)$, which is defined as
$$I_\alpha(x) := i^{-\alpha} J_\alpha(i x) \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{m! \Gamma(m + \alpha + 1)} \left(\frac{x}2\right)^{2 m + \alpha} .$$
Here, $J_\alpha(x)$ is the (unmodified) [Bessel Function of the First Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1), which satisfies a similar differential equation.

Fixing $\alpha = 0$ gives
$$I_0(x) = J_0(i x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!^2} \left(\frac{x}2\right)^{2 m},$$
and setting $x = 2$ gives that our sum is
$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!^2} = I_0(2) = J_0(-2 i) = 2.279585302\ldots .$$

More generally, substituting $u = \frac{x^2}{4}$ in our expression for $I_0(x)$ gives that the series in @KamalSaleh's comment has value
$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{u^i}{i!^2} = I_0(2 \sqrt u)$$ for suitable $u$.

Alternatively, it follows from the definition of [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series) that we can write
$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!^2} = {}_0 F_1(1; 1) ,$$
and more generally that
$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{u^m}{m!^2} = {}_0 F_1(1; u) .$$

(Even) more generally, for positive integers $k$,
$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{u^m}{m!^k} = {}_0 F_{k - 1}(\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{k - 1}; u) .$$

Where the summands are defined, where $|u| < 1$ and as $k \searrow 0$, linearizing the series in $u$ gives the expansion
$$\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{u^m}{m!^k} \sim \frac{1}{1 - u} - \sum_{m = 0}^\infty u^m \log (m!) \cdot k + R(k) ,$$ where $R(k) \in O(k^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

The Bessel Clifford function is defined as (for $n=0$) $$C_0(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{k!^2}$$So your sum is equivalent to the integral$$C_0(1)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{2\cos\theta}d\theta=\frac1{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{2\cos\theta}d\theta$$Which doesn't seem to be solvable.

Credit to @TymaGaidash for making me aware of this function.

Comment: Showing that the value of the series is equal to that integral is a nice exercise in contour integration, by the way.

Comment: I am not that fluent with contour integration, but I had a feeling that it would be the way to solve the integral because of the $\frac1{2\pi}$ in front of the integral. I can't perform contour integration with finite boundaries.

Comment: In this case the substitution $z = \exp(i \theta)$ transforms the integral over $[0, 2\pi]$ into a contour integral over the unit circle. In particular, $\cos \theta = \frac12 \left(z + \frac1z\right)$ along the curve. Then, the Residue Theorem can be applied.